# AWS data pipeline -"Full copy of rds mysql table to s3" no connection string in parameters?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm currently working on my first pipeline copying data from RDS to S3. I'm following the guidelines provided by Amazon (see below). There isn't a RDS MySQL connection string field for my case. Anyone why this might be?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-mysql-console.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **RDS MySQL connection string** field is no more available, there is an input field to provide the **RDS Instance ID** instead. 
[image: RDS ID input field]
Provide the ID of your RDS instance, the JDBC connection string will be derived using it.

Comment: I filled out the all the fields, activated the pipeline and got a "connect timed out" error. Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Did you happen to change the Default port of Mysql when creating the RDS instance? and also both the Pipeline and RDS are created in same region?

Comment: The pipeline and RDS are in the same region. I did not create the RDS instance. Is there a way to find if if the Default port has or has not been changed?

Comment: In the RDS console, select the DB instance to view the instance details. Also verify the security group of the RDS instance the EC2 group given in pipeline.